# How to communicate two apps using Socket.IO?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, socket.io

I have created two simple apps. One is an React(Web) and second React-native. I found that Socket.io is a great tool for socket communication. But i stuck....

There is a client (React WebPage) :

```
useEffect(() => {
socket.on('resetVerdict',()=>{alert('Reset!')});
 }, [socket]);
```

We have also server:

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http'; 

const app = express(); 
const server = http.createServer(app); 

app.use(cors());

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

 socket.on('resetVerdict',()=>{
    console.log('Zresetowano!');
  })

});

const port = 4000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Serwer Socket.io nasłuchuje na porcie ${port}`);
});
```

And second client (Sender) :

```
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { server } from './server';
export default function MainPage() {
    const resetVerdict = () => {
      server.emit('resetVerdict');
    }
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>MainPage</Text>
      <Button title='Click' onPress={resetVerdict} color='red'/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

If i emit 'resetVerdict' straight at server, React client get message and show Alert.
But if i emit 'resetVerdict' at React-native client, the first client (web) doesnt get anything.
Where is the problem ?

I tryied to emmit 'resetVerdict' at server and it works, but this is not the target.

Comment: All messages pass through your server. It's up to you to relay messages from there to other clients. See `https://socket.io/docs/v3/broadcasting-events/#to-all-connected-clients-except-the-sender`. You can do this inside of the `resetVerdict` handler in the server file. It works when you do an emit from the server because...well you are emitting an event to connected clients. The reason it doesn't work from from the react-native app is you are sending the message to the server, which then does nothing with it. Theres no direct connection between the app and the web. The server must coordinate.

Comment: Thank you for your help !!!  It works now.